# Using hypercomputation for "impossible" problems?

Tags: computability, logic, oracle-machines, philosophy, hypercomputation

In mathematics and philosophy there are some unsolvable problems like [Russell's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) or [the liar's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox) that are usually said to be undecidable... There are also other "impossibilities" such as finding positive integers to divide a prime number other than the number itself and 1.

However, could we use some kind of hypercomputer or an oracle that could theoretically give the solutions to these problems? Perhaps through some special kind of computational processes based on alternative forms of logic?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/52196/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/155696/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 5):

Nope.

Russell's paradox and the liar's paradox aren't undecidable.  They aren't even decision problems.

As far as we know, hypercomputers don't exist.  They are an imaginary idea that don't appear likely to exist in the real world.  We use them as a thought experiment to imagine what the consequences would be if we had a hypothetical device that could do something that no computer can do.  So, no, you can't use them to do anything in the real world since they don't exist.

In any case, no, hypercomputers, even if they existed, would not solve those paradoxes, because those paradoxes are not undecidable decision problems -- they aren't even decision problems, so computability is basically irrelevant to them.

Comment: and could these paradoxes be solved somehow? Or could we find positive integers that would divide a prime number other than 1 and itself? @D.W.

Comment: @vengaq, there is a tremendous amount that has been written on Russell's paradox and the liar's paradox.  They are largely not a matter of computer science, so I'm not sure that is in scope here on this site, and in any case, that would be a separate question.  It might be more helpful to think of each paradox as something puzzling to be understood more deeply, rather than as a problem to be solved.  Typically when you encounter a paradox, that is more a sign of incomplete understanding than of a problem to be solved.  I don't believe that hypercomputation offers any great insights into them.